# Combine two pg.draw.circle into one element on pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I know that you can combine two `pygame.draw.rect` by the `unionall` method.
And how to combine two circles?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot combine two [pygame.draw.circle](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle) calls into one call. You also cannot combine two [`pygame.draw.rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect) calls into one call. These functions only draw on the screen. All you can do is calculate the bounding rectangle of two [pygame.Rect](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects with [`union`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.union) or [`unionall`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.unionall). However, the bounding rectangle of 2 objects is something completely different from the objects themselves.

```py
rect1 = pygame.Rect(100, 100, 100, 50)
rect2 = pygame.Rect(150, 200, 100, 50)
union_rect = rect1.union(rect2)

pygame.draw.rect(window, (96, 96, 96), rect1)
pygame.draw.rect(window, (96, 96, 96), rect2)
pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), union_rect, 3)
```

[image]

However, you can calculate the bounding rectangles of individual circles and calculate the bounding rectangle of all circles:

```py
rect1 = pygame.draw.circle(window, (96, 96, 96), (100, 100), 50)
rect2 = pygame.draw.circle(window, (96, 96, 96), (200, 150), 50)
union_rect = rect1.union(rect2)
pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), union_rect, 3)
```

[image]